# What is flag-wagging (possible: flag wagging)?

Tags: word-meaning

I found a word *flag-wagging* in a dictionary, but couldn't find any *en-en* definitions or references. What is it? It is used in modern English?

Is it, by any chance, a synonym for *sabre-rattling*?

Comment: I think *flag-wagging* is just a variant of *flag-waving*.

Answer (score 5):

**Flag wagging** (BrE) is equivalent to **flag waving** (AmE) and usage was at its height during the 1940's, declining since [**here**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=flag+wagging&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cflag%20wagging%3B%2Cc0).  Both expressions are used to express **enthusiastic and patriotic displays using a flag** as opposed to the more sedate expression

> **Flying the flag**

A quote from George Orwell's (yes **the** George Orwell) booklet *The Lion and The Unicorn: Socialism and the English Genius* uses [**flag-wagging**](http://www.orwell.ru/library/essays/lion/english/e_eye)

> In England all the boasting and **flag-wagging**, the 'Rule Britannia' stuff, is done by small minorities.

It was written in 1941.  Usage of **flag-wagging** seems to be dated.